# ¿Cómo puedo sumar Números dentro de una lista?

Tags: python

Intento sumar números dentro de una lista. Este es mi código:

```
Datos = [int(input('Coloca un Número: ')) + int(input('Coloca otro Número: ')) + int(input('Coloca otro Número: '))]

Media = Datos / 3

print(Media)
```

Pero, obtengo este error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for 'list' and 'int'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bien, acá tenemos dos problemas.

El primero es que la instrucción

```
Datos = [int(input('Coloca un Número: ')) + int(input('Coloca otro Número: ')) + int(input('Coloca otro Número: '))]
```

crea una lista de un solo elemento, ya que

```
int(input('Coloca un Número: ')) + int(input('Coloca otro Número: ')) + int(input('Coloca otro Número: '))
```

devuelve la suma de todos los números que ingrese el usuario como un solo número entero.

El segundo consiste en que la instrucción

```
Media = Datos / 3
```

intenta realizar una operación inválida, ya que `Datos` es una lista y `3` un número entero.

Ahí el error `"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for 'list' and 'int'"` porque, ¿cómo divides una lista entre un número?

Si corregimos esto, queda de esta forma:

```
conteo = 3   # Cantidad de veces que el programa pide un número al usuario
datos  = []

for i in range(conteo):
    numero = int(input('Coloca un Número: '))
    datos.append(numero)
    
media = sum(datos) / conteo

print(media)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, de todo corazón, me sirvió. Te doy la aprobación. :)

Comment: No es una matriz. Solo tiene una dimensión así que lo correcto sería referirse como vector, lista o arreglo.

Comment: @Mateo Agradezco tu observación. Lo he corregido.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Otra forma de hacerlo es dividiendo el `string` en los números ingresados con [`split`](https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/paginas-web/desarrollo-web/python-split/#:%7E:text=Con%20Python%20split%2C%20el%20lenguaje,los%20par%C3%A1metros%20separator%20y%20maxsplit.), luego convertirlos a enteros y creando una lista utilizando [`map`](https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/funcion-map) en combinación con `list`

Luego puedes utilizar la `sum` para obtener la suma de todos los elementos de la lista y `len` para obtener el tamaño de la lista, esto te permitirá obtener la media para cualquier tamaño de lista y no lo limitas a 3 números:

Ejemplo:

```
valores = list(map(int, input('Ingresa los valores que deseas sumar separados por un espacio:').split()))
print(f'Media = {sum(valores)/len(valores)}')
```

Muestra de funcionamiento:

```
Ingresa los valores que deseas sumar separados por un espacio: 1 2 3 4 5
Media = 3.0
```

### Edición

Gracias al comentario de @CandidMoe, agrego también la versión con la comprensión de listas

```
valores = [int(x) for x in input('Ingresa los valores que deseas sumar separados por un espacio:').split()]
print(f'Media = {sum(valores)/len(valores)}')
```

Comment: Opino que `map()` es una función innecesaria en Python y debe ser descartada. Puedes lograr lo mismo con una simple comprensión de lista, que es más clara y versátil: `valores = [int(x) for x in input('Ingresa los valores que deseas sumar separados por un espacio:').split()]
`

Comment: Entiendo el comentario @CandidMoe. Se entiende mejor con una comprensión de listas. Edité la respuesta, lo había puesto con `map()` porque en lo personal casi nunca la uso y como existe pues simplemente la quería usar jaja

Comment: Pasa lo mismo con `filter()`, otra función que puedes sustituir con comprensión de listas.